# React Axios catch not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to learn React and i'm working with Axios to do XHR API calls. So like with everything I do, the first thing to do is read the documentation. I implemented a XHR call following the documentation on: https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware#dispatch-action

Somehow, when the request fail's the `.then()` clause is triggered instead of the `.catch` clause.

I am beating my head silly on what is going wrong and I am not able to figure it out. Below there is how I implemented Axios:

App.js:

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL:'http://localhost:8080/api',
  responseType: 'json'
});

const axiosMiddle = axiosMiddleware(client)
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, axiosMiddle)(createStore)
```

Component.js:

```
handleLogin(event) {
  const credentials = {
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
  }
  this.props.login(credentials)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      console.log('SUCCESS')
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      console.log('ERROR')
    })
}
```

Action.js:

```
export function login(credentials) {
  return {
    type: ['LOAD','AWESOME','OH_NO'],
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: '/login/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          username: credentials.username,
          password: credentials.password
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the console.log output:

```
HTTP Failure in Axios Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
Root.jsx:82 {type: "LOAD,AWESOME,OH_NO_FAIL", error: {…}, meta: {…}}error: {data: "Network Error", status: 0}meta: {previousAction: {…}}type: "LOAD,AWESOME,OH_NO_FAIL"__proto__: Object
Root.jsx:83 SUCCESS
```

Slowly I am going crazy and somehow I dont know how to fix it. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In component.js, your login is not doing any asynchronous call, instead, it just returns an object, no error can happen there, that's why it always ends up "SUCCESS". And the console.log(response) always print the object returned by login.

So, instead of simply returning the object, you should actually do the asynchronous request. The way to actually do the request is by `dispatch(login(credentials))`.

BTW, the error you got has nothing to do with login, it happened in axios.create in App.js.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am figuring how to do the action handling of errors but I hope I will be able to solve it by learning.

Thanks for your help.